# _mm256_testz_pd not working?

Tags: x86, g++, intel, simd, avx

I'm working on Core i7 on Linux and using g++ 4.63.

I tried the following code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <immintrin.h>

int main() {
__m256d a = _mm256_set_pd(1,2,3,4);
__m256d z = _mm256_setzero_pd();
std::cout << _mm256_testz_pd(a,a) << std::endl;
std::cout << _mm256_testz_pd(z,z) << std::endl;
std::cout << _mm256_testz_pd(a,z) << std::endl;
}
```

It printed 3 1's. I was expecting at least one of them to be 0.

I tried using `_mm256_castpd_si256` and then `_mm256_testz_si256`, it'll print 0 for the first line.

Why?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Whereas `_mm256_testz_si256` (`VPTEST`) operates on all bits in the source vectors, `_mm256_testz_pd` (`VTESTPD`) only operates on the *sign bit* of each double precision element. In your test all the sign bits in both vectors are zero, so you're getting the correct result.

Comment: Wait a minute. If I'm reading your answer correctly, [this](http://software.intel.com/sites/products/documentation/studio/composer/en-us/2011Update/compiler_c/intref_cls/common/intref_avx_testz_pd.htm) says otherwise. It looks like it's bitwise ANDing the two operands. Then for each element, it returns true if the result is zero.

Comment: I suspect that page needs correcting - the latest version of the Intel Intrinsics Guide (2.8.1) says: *Compute the bitwise AND of 256 bits (representing double-precision (64-bit) floating-point elements) in a and b, producing an intermediate 256-bit value, and set ZF to 1 if the sign bit of each 64-bit element in the intermediate value is zero, otherwise set ZF to 0. Compute the bitwise AND NOT of a and b, producing an intermediate value, and set CF to 1 if the sign bit of each 64-bit element in the intermediate value is zero, otherwise set CF to 0. Return the ZF value.*

Comment: Wow, even [this version](http://software.intel.com/sites/products/documentation/doclib/stdxe/2013/composerxe/compiler/cpp-mac/GUID-8EFAEC85-AC33-412C-BD09-68A740AD5764.htm) of the docs say the same thing.

Comment: I expect it's a copy-paste error (copying from `_mm256_testz_si256`) that's been propagated throughout the documentation - at least it's fixed in the Intrinsics Guide, which is what I tend to use for reference.

Comment: No problem - it seems that some versions of the documentation are incorrect so you may not even have misread it.